# w=-1-4i, find the modulus and argument of this in polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

For my answer I got 4.5 and when you sketch -1-4i on the Argand diagram, it is in third quadrant. So when I did arctan(4), I got 1.3 and then I did pi+ 1.3 which gave me 4.467.. However, in the answer it says that it is 1.3. I am unsure whether there is a mistake in the mark-scheme or I did something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjugate is $\bar{w}=-1+4i$, so the product is $w\bar{w}=1+16=17$; the modulus is $\sqrt{17}\approx 4.1231$.

The argument should certainly be an angle in the third quadrant. You have correctly done
$$
\arctan 4\approx 1.3258
$$
and the argument is
$$
\pi+\arctan 4\approx 4.4674
$$